# How create a button Close screen for multi platform in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is MainPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout >
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="LOGIN" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Text="Email:" />
        <Entry x:Name="txtEmail"  Margin = "0, -5,0,0"  />
        <Label Text="Password:" />
        <Entry x:Name="txtPassword"  Margin = "0, -5,0,0" />
        <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Text="Login"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" Text="Close" Clicked="OnClose"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

This is code of MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code close screen
        }
    }
```

How can close target screen for multi platform(Android, ios, UWP)?
Thank all.

Comment: Admittedly I am not quite sure what you are talking about. Do you want to close your whole app, or do you want to close the `MainPage` only. And in case of the letter: What should be showed after closing the `MainPage`?

Comment: I only want close MainPage. ex: in android call finish()

Answer (score 1):

You should follow coding against Interface for the scenario that you mentioned, create an Interface in your Xamarin.Forms project and than Implement that interface in all the platforms that you are supporting.

Considering that you want to close the App itself, refer to below architecture which might help you. You can modify it accordingly that fits your business case.

```
Public Interface IPerformPlatformSpecificOperations
{
  void CloseApplication();
}

Android:

Public Class AndroidSpecificOperations : IPerformPlatformSpecificOperations
{
   public void CloseApplication()
   {
     //Platform Specific Code
   }
}

UWP: 

Public Class UWPSpecificOperations : IPerformPlatformSpecificOperations
{
   public void CloseApplication()
   {
     //Platform Specific Code
   }
}

iOS:

Public Class iOSSpecificOperations : IPerformPlatformSpecificOperations
{
   public void CloseApplication()
   {
     //Platform Specific Code
   }
}
```

Use some IoC library to inject dependencies and than call `CloseApplication()` in your Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: Hi, in Android: i using Finish() function, but in IOS exist function support?

Comment: For iOS there's no direct way to exit the application, but you can try [this](http://www.redbitdev.com/exiting-ios-app-with-xamarin-ios/)